# Control page access using codeigniter roles and paypal pro

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-2

I want to control access to a page,Only members who paid are allowed to access this page.

I thought about a solution which is adding an attribute to User model.
this attribute is a Boolean,it indicates if a user status is paid or not,it is modified after the Paypal payment done.

the second solution is to create a Role 'user_p' which is set after the payment verified.

if you have any suggestions or code examples.

Comment: I would go with updating DB table/column when payment is done. On login you would add that condition like where username and password and payment. Yes it could be boolean or date if there is payment period expiration that should be compared with date of login.

Comment: i think when a user become paid.he should be 1 in db column.

Comment: So the best approach is to use a database column.what about using a new role.

Comment: keep in mind you also need to track expiration